# <!doctype html> forces the code to not display correctly

Tags: javascript, css, html, frontend

I start making a page without 
`<!doctype html>`,
but when I add this line with 
`<!doctype html>`
my code doesn't display correctly. Where is the problem? (and please sorry if my code seems bad, difficult and with mistakes.

I am just a newcomer in front-end. I will very thankful if you help me.

[with !doctype html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eD1X6.png)

[without !doctype html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFbwS.png)

```
<html>
<head>
 <title> Repear phones, laptops, tablets. Replacement screen, battery, touch screen. Unlock and re-flashing phone.</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
 <div class="visit-card">
   <div class="visit-card__part-1">
     <table class="visit-card__part-1__table">
       <tr>
         <td class="visit-card__part-1__table__logo">
           <img class="visit-card__part-1__logo" src="images/servis-plus.png" alt="Service-plus.by">
         </td>
         <td class="visit-card__part-1__table__tel-1">
           <span class="visit-card__part-1__table__tel-1__number">+375291386105</span> <br /> <span class="visit-card__part-1__table__tel-1__time">10:00-20:00</span><span class="visit-card__part-1__table__tel-1__empty">11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</span
         </td>
         <td class="visit-card__part-1__table__empty-block">
         </td>
         <td class="visit-card__part-1__table__tel-2">
           +375293711698
         </td>
       </tr>
     </table>
   </div>
   <div class="visit-card__part-2">
     <div class="visit-card__part-2__headline"> Quickly need <br /> repair device?
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
 </body>
</html>


body {
margin: 0;
}

.visit-card {
width: 1280px;
height: 750px;
background-size: 1280px 750px;
background-image: url(images/main-bg.jpg);
}

.visit-card__part-1__logo {
width: 191px;
height: 78px;
}

.visit-card__part-1__table {
width: 100%;
height: 140px;
color: white;
font-family: arial;
font-size: 24;
border-bottom: 1px solid #80705c;
}

.visit-card__part-1__table__logo {
text-align: right;
width: 270px; 
}

.visit-card__part-1__table__tel-1 {
text-align: right;
vertical-align: top;
}

.visit-card__part-1__table__tel-2 {
vertical-align: top;
}

.visit-card__part-1__table__tel-1__time {
font-size: 17;
line-height: 1%;
}

.visit-card__part-1__table__tel-1__empty {
visibility: hidden;
font-size: 1;
}

.visit-card__part-1__table__tel-1__number {
line-height: 75px;
}

.visit-card__part-1__table__tel-2 {
line-height: 75px;
}

.visit-card__part-1__table__empty-block {
width: 65px;
}

.visit-card__part-2__headline {
color: white;
}
```

Comment: There is a typo in the code example. One of your closing span blocks is </span, not </span>.  I'm not sure if that's your problem, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you add `<!doctype html>` you need to be more careful with your html and css. First fix the `span` typo in the closing tag. But then you also need to add units to your font sizes in css:

For example:

```
.visit-card__part-1__table__tel-1__time {
   font-size: 17px;
   line-height: 1%;
}
```

It *needs* to be `17px` not `17`. I think there are three font sizes in your css with no units. Changing this should fix it.